# How to call a Directive/Component's function inside rendered Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Using "this" inside renderer function goes as undefined. how can i pass this inside the function? or is there any other method to watch the scroll and achieve the same?

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {
      this.Scroll();
}

constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    this.el = el;
    this.renderer = renderer;
}

Scroll():void{
this.renderer.listen(this.e[0], 'scroll', (event: any, ):void => {
     //want to call Directives function here
    //ex: this.someFunc()
    },true);
 }
```

i event tried the JavaScript method

```
this.e[0].addEventListener('scroll', function (e: any) {
//ex: this.someFunc()
 });
```

Comment: This just works. How and from where is the code in your question being called?

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: when i try to call a function like `this.scrolled()` it throws an error-> Cannot read property 'scrolled' of undefined

Comment: The `this.renderer.listen...` code should work, the "JavaScript" code can't work because you use `function (e: any) {` instead of `(e:any) => {`

Answer (score 0):

this keyword is not working inside event function definition as it is not in this function's scope. To make it work, you can save 'this' scope in a function variable and use it inside event function definition.

```
Scroll():void{
var self = this;
this.renderer.listen(this.e[0], 'scroll', (event: any, ):void => {
     //use self instead of this
    //ex: self.someFunc()
    },true);
 }
```

Hope this helps.